# Double click makes hover state go away on a div

Tags: css, hover

Double click on a `div` makes `hover` state go away. I want to persist `hover` state as long as the `cursor` is on the `div`. How to achieve this without using JS?

10sec video of issue: https://youtu.be/uZlyH2d-Z-M

Code:

```css
div{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:green
}

div:hover{
 background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This issue isn't replicated by your snippet, or this http://jsfiddle.net/wj9b3gn4/

Comment: yes I am using chrome version 67.0.3396.79

Comment: Yes I tried on firefox but its not reproducible. Only on chrome. Mine is chrome 68+.

Comment: @rileyjsumner I have attached a 10 sec video

Comment: Your link is broken...

Comment: It will work now. Pls check. Thanks.